# Why didn't Darth Sidious have Darth Tyranus destroy the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, sith, darth-sidious, darth-tyranus

Why didn't Darth Sidious have Darth Tyranus lead Order 66 in the Jedi Temple, since Palpatine knew that Dooku ordered the clones? Darth Tyranus is one of the best swordsman in the galaxy and he is a powerful sith lord, so why did Palpatine wait for Vader to lead Order 66 in the Jedi Temple? Why did Sidious choose Vader to lead Order 66 in the Jedi Temple?

**EDIT:** I already change the question to be more clear and accurate.

Comment: Vader didn't destroy the Jedi. Order 66 did. And Order 66 wasn't set up until the end of the Clone Wars, which needed a figurehead Sith enemy to keep the Jedi off Sidious' trail -- Dooku.

Comment: Vader also destroy the Jedi only in the Jedi temple. And why did Sidious decides to give Vader and his troops the Order 66 in action

Comment: Palpatine was smart and patient waiting for the right moment. This could happen even now, on our planet if a senator is smart enough.

Comment: I gotta admit, I don't really understand what you're asking. Why did Sidious do XYZ? Because he thought it would be effective to further his goals. Why else?

Comment: @anakindchosenone05192005 Vader had some guards, but most of the clones were already embedded in the Republic and Jedi army. So for them it was as simple as turning around and shooting the guy with a lightsaber. And Vader *did* kill Jedi in the temple, but there weren't nearly as many there as there were out in the field fighting the false war Sidious made.

Comment: My question is simple,Why Sidious waited for Vader to destroy the Jedi?Why he did;nt have it for Tyranus or Maul instead. Imagine that in ROTS scene marching at the temple , Instead of Darth Vader with his troops marching, Darth Maul or Darth Tyranus were replaced to Darth Vader.

Comment: @anakindchosenone05192005 The troops were still in development during Maul's time. And if Sidious had had Dooku besiege the Jedi with the clone army instead of going through the whole Clone Wars creation ordeal, the Jedi wouldn't have been caught by surprise -- which is one of the few ways to kill Jedi, barring a snipe from a thousand miles away!

Comment: Because both Darth Tyranus and Darth Maul were dead? Yes, even Darth Maul, by the time *Revenge of the Sith* was made.

Comment: @anakindchosenone05192005 I honestly can't, because "what if" questions aren't accepted.  I like that you're curious about it, but I feel like going through the movies again with this discussion in mind will answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: Terriblefan, at least I'm curious which makes me smarter

Comment: Yes, but Darth Maul returned in The Clone Wars.

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar actually that has been expanded on. In The newer Darth Vader comic series (Darth Lord of the Sith), Sidious sent Vader on various tasks to further his transition. This included hunting down some remaining Jedi.

Comment: @Ellesedil, yes but if you truly wanted to understand a character, you need to do more than just generalize, you need to understand not just that they have goals, but that they have goals to "what ends" and "how" they do it, tells us a bit more about whom they really are.

Answer (score 5):

**Sidious had the opportunity to replace his previous apprentices with a young, extremely powerful apprentice (Vader) by the time he was ready to issue Order 66.**

Darth Maul was defeated by Obi-Wan on Naboo (and lost his position as Sidious' apprentice) before the clone army was ready, so Order 66 could not be issued while Maul was Sidious' apprentice.

Maul was replaced with Tyranus, who in his position of leadership in the Confederacy of Independent States helped foment the Clone Wars -- a conflict that was necessary to distract and set up the Jedi for mass execution by the clones. Since Order 66 was mainly carried out by the clones anyway (the attack on the Jedi Temple was only one of many simultaneous attacks on the Jedi), it didn't make much difference whether Tyranus or Vader led the attack; it would have been theoretically possible for Sidious to have Tyranus lead the attack on the Jedi Temple *if* Tyranus was still Sidious' apprentice by that time. However, [Sidious knew he could seduce Anakin to the dark side and was able to get rid of the aging Tyranus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/79415/31936) by the time he was ready to issue Order 66.

Sidious was always looking for a more powerful apprentice -- it's the same reason why he later wanted to replace the injured and aging Vader with his son, Luke.

Comment: Is it a matter of appearance

Answer (score 0):

The main reason was that Count Dooku was the leader of the Separitists. To have him lead clones into the temple would make no sense.  He had to die so Anakin could become Vader. Dooku's usefullness was at an end.

Comment: Put in mind that Dooku knows order 66. Plus he ordered the Clone Army.

Comment: All I'm saying is that it is foolish to have the leader of the CIS leading the enemy army.

Comment: Well, in fact dooku is playing with the CIS already to the point that his master is playing both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Sidious had been planning this for quite some time.  Plagueis conceived Anakin directly from the force in an attempt to replace Sidious, which is why he murdered his master in his sleep.  Sidious had been out to figure out who the vergence in the force was and claim that person as his own apprentice. This is all pretty standard stuff in the expanded novelizations and graphic novels.  What I don't think Sidious planned on was Darth Vader getting himself crippled.  One constant theme in 'The Rise of Darth Vader' and in the Darth Vader graphic novels was in how disappointed Sidious was in his new apprentice and how weak, comparatively, Vader had become.  Anakin Skywalker was a true force bad-ass. Darth Vader was creepy and scary but was not nearly as powerful as he once was.  Please don't ask me for quotes or page numbers.  This is my recollection.